# How to remove gaussian noise and poisson noise?

Tags: noise

I want to remove the noise gaussian and poisson noise.
But I'm unfamilier with noise remove methods but from my understanding it's similler to average filter which is median filter.
But I want to know exactly how to remove those kind of noise.

My interest is in image.
And I think that if I make an image with gassian noise +poisson noise then I have to use two remove stages. But I'm not sure whether can I use just one median filter to remove all noise or there are especially methds in there.

Comment: The answer will depend on what the noise is contaminating and what you want to do with the signal being contaminated. The methods applicable in digital communications (e.g. matched filtering) _severely distort_ the signal and thus are not suitable for removing the noise from an audio signal that someone might want to listen to after the noise removal.  -1 pending your edits that clarify what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate My interest is in image.
And I think that if I make an image with gassian noise +poisson noise then I have to use two remove stages. But I'm not sure whether can I use just one median filter to remove all noise or there are especially methds in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove noise from an image corrupted by a mixture of Poisson-Gaussian noise (e.g. low photon counts lead to a Poisson noise component, and detector noise gives the Gaussian component) then there are couple of options:

- Apply a variance-stabilizing transform such as the Anscombe Transform to essentially make the noise Gaussian, then use any technique for additive Gaussian noise removal. A good example is *Optimal inversion of the Anscombe and Generalized Anscombe variance-stabilizing transformations*, Mäkitalo & Foi (2014), [paper](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~foi/papers/OptGenAnscombeInverse-doublecolumn-preprint.pdf) and [code](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~foi/invansc/)
- Work with the Poisson-Gaussian statistics directly. For example, *Image Denoising in Mixed Poisson–Gaussian Noise*, Luisier *et al.* (2011), [paper](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/publications/luisier1101.pdf) and [code](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/algorithms/denoise/) are available.

Comment: Should I have to treat it by separately?

Comment: @gmotree Both methods do a single treatment, but approach it in different ways.