# Techniques for variance stabilizing? Filtering Poisson noise?

Tags: noise

This question is solely theory related so there isn't any sort of practical implementation I'm doing.
I'd like to know what are the different techniques for variance stabilizing(not necessarily used for Poisson noise), and if there's somewhere I can read some detailed explanations of those.
Also I am interested in methods used for removing Poisson noise (the one I found is Ascombe transform, which is technique for variance stabilizing at the same time), again the same goes here, if there's some detailed explanations of these it'd be really great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [link](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/384E/vartrans.pdf) explaining variance stabilizing transform.

Some papers on Poisson noise removal

1. [Efficient gradient projection methods for edge-preserving removal of Poisson noise](http://www.disi.unige.it/person/BerteroM/papers-PDF/IP2009.pdf)
2. [Wavelets,Ridgelets and Curvelets for Poisson Noise removal](https://hal-pasteur.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00259509/document)(Anscombe transform is used here)
3. [Unsupervised Non Local Means for Poisson Noise](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~cdeledal/files/articleICIP2010.pdf)

Similar question has been asked before: [How to remove Poisson and Gaussian Noise?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24023/how-to-remove-gaussian-noise-and-poisson-noise)